# Backup Microsoft fabric and prevent easy artifact deletion

Tags: backup-strategies, warehouse, data-lakehouse, microsoft-fabric

We are considering to move our "classical" SQL data warehouse over to microsoft fabric.

I noticed two things which both are possible showstoppers:

1. I cant find any information on backups. How can we backup a fabric workspace (or at least a fabric warehouse or lakehouse), including all its content and data (tables, shortcuts, views, stored procedures etc.)?
2. With only two clicks, eg. a warehouse or lakehouse (and all other artifacts) can be deleted. Everything attached to it along the lineage is deleted as well. So, with only two clicks, eg. a warehouse is deleted, including (in our case) hundreds of tables, hundreds of shortcuts, dozens of stored procedures, dozens of views. Also it automatically deletes all datasets, reports etc. that are attached to the deleted warehouse or lakehouse. All deleted in only two clicks.
   Is it possible to prevent that anyone who has access can delete all these objects so easily?[image: delete step 1]
   [image: delete step 2]

Comment: That second thing is scary especially without an answer on the first thing.

Comment: For 1) You use git integration and devops pipelines to control the code. Its in the workspace settings, to back up the data you'll need to archive it to another storage account. 2)  You will control it using normal workspace access setting, admin, contributors and read only, like you would do in Power BI. 3) Fabric is not in GA yet and features are being added rapidly, such as control in the tenant setting for users and groups and their actions

Answer (score 0):

Workspace recovery and more git support are on the roadmap for Q4 2023. Start building and testing. There are things you can do in Fabric that are just straight up impossible with a non-Fabric warehouse.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/release-plan/admin-governance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/release-plan/data-engineering